# zip function on 2 lists removes values

Tags: python

I noticed that zip() removes exactly 2 values.

I have 2 lists: `descrp` and `author` and both lists have length of 25. When I use zip() to make dictionary it changes length of keys and values to 23. In addition, the `author` list have 25 same values (which is correct).

Descrp's values are name of commits from BitBucket repository and author are name of author to each commit. These values are **scraped** from website

```
print(len(descrp)) #25
print(len(author)) #25

dict1 = dict(zip(descrp,author))
print(len(dict1.keys()) #23
print(len(dict1.values()) #23
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Post complete code. You forgot to post, at least, the definition of `descrp` and `author`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I added

Comment: You obviously have duplicate values in descrp.  The dictionary will only keep one of them (the last one)

Comment: @AlainT. Doesn't it keep the *first* one (since you're talking about the keys).

Comment: Complete code means that someone can copy-paste the code and run it. Not that you explain in vague terms what the missing code does.

Comment: @ HeapOverflow, I meant it keeps the last key/value pair.

Comment: @AlainT. That doesn't sound right, either. For example `dict(zip([1, True], [2, 3]))` gets me `{1: 3}`, which is neither of the two original key/value pairs.

Comment: @ HeapOverflow, that's because 1 and True produce the same hash value so they are considered to be the same key. But the first key and the last value are kept and I agree that my statement was inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `descrp` have duplicates? I see only in that case this can happen as the keys of the dict have to be unique. You can check this by doing

```
len(set(descrp)) == len(descrp)
```

The `set` removes the duplicates.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. When I inspected this repo it turned out there are 2 the same commits, so the value will be ok